# Server object error 'ASP 0177 : c0000005'

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

The full error:

```
 The CreateObject of '(null)' caused exception C0000005.
 Server object error 'ASP 0177 : c0000005'
 Server.CreateObject Failed
 /get.asp, line 35
```

get.asp - line 35:

```
 Response.Status = "500 Internal Server Error"
 set objErr=Server.GetLastError()

 Col = objErr.Column
 Cat = objErr.Category
 Desc = objErr.Description
 Fle = objErr.File
 Lne = objErr.Line
 Num = objErr.Number
 Src = objErr.Source
 ASPC = objErr.ASPCode
 ASPD = objErr.ASPDescription

 set SQLCOMM = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")  //line 35
 SQLCOMM.ActiveConnection = DBConn_Str
 SQLCOMM.CommandText = SQLq
 SQLCOMM.CommandType = 1
 SQLCOMM.CommandTimeout = 0
 SQLCOMM.Prepared = true
 SQLCOMM.Execute()
 set SQLCOMM=Nothing
```

This script usually works, but for some odd reason it keeps giving this error every now and then lately.  The most recent thing i did is make more table/col indexes in the MsSql DB, and i'm not sure why this is now happening.  Does anybody know why?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8550695/825789).

Comment: What error brings you to this page in the first place?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I have no idea because `GetLastError()` isn't pulling it up.

Comment: But it means some other page caused error, thus you are redirected to the error page. Anyway - if you try to write to plain text file instead, does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is a windows Access Denied error.  However what it disturbing is that it is an *exception* C00000005 rather than an *error* 80070005.  Somewhere between `CreateObject` and the completion of initialising an `ADODB.Command` an access denied exception is being raised that isn't caught by normal means.

At this point in code the only thing being "accessed" is the ADODB.dll however its unlikely that this is truely a permissions problem.  However if you are using windows integrated security on the site it my be worth seeing if there is a corelation between occurances and the user using the site.

Comment: This is actually being run on an error catching script that is used by custom error '500.100'.  I just posted some more code above, and usually when i get the error, i get a few instances at once, so i get multiple errors of the same on the page.. So it may be another reason this error is happening, it uses 'Server.GetLastError()', please see revised code above in `get.asp`

Comment: I have a feeling the Server.GetLastError() is crashing somehow and causing the rest of the script to crash somehow, i'm confused..

Comment: The `objErr` wasn't being closed.. Once i set it to nothing, error hasn't happened since, same stress levels.. I'm an idiot ;), i gave u best answer for sticking around.. Thanks again Anthony!